# Confused on ES6 Object Syntax

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I'm reading about the new [ECMAScript 2015](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#arrows) features and came across a code example that doesn't make sense to me under the **Arrows** heading.

```
// Lexical this
var bob = {
  _name: "Bob",
  _friends: [],
  printFriends() {
    this._friends.forEach(f =>
      console.log(this._name + " knows " + f));
  }
}
```

How is `printFriends() {...` operating here? It's not a method because there's no colon. It's not a private function because there's no `function` keyword. What am I missing here?

Comment: That's the ES2015 way of defining methods in object literals.

Comment: Yeah, it's syntactic sugar. It is essentially the same as `printFriends: function() { ...`.

Comment: ES2015  aimed to eliminate the need the use of the word function. so the above is a simple example of defining a function as a object's property like vohuman said

Answer (score 4):

As you can read on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions), ES2015 supports shorthand for defining object methods:

ES5

```
var obj = {
  foo: function() {},
  bar: function() {}
};
```

and ES2015 shorthand:

```
var obj = {
  foo() {},
  bar() {}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The printFriends() { ...} is shorthand for function printFriends () {...}
Because printFriends doesn't accept any parameters you can just use () in place of function printFriends.

[See mozilla arrow function docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: His question isn't about the arrow function, it's about defining a function without having `property:` before it.

Comment: it has nothing to do with parameters, with or without params it works the same

Comment: @NetaMeta do you really not need the keyword `function` in ES6? Or am I understanding what @dcooke said incorrectly?

Comment: In object or classes you can drop the word function completely and provide the name and parameter and it will work just like es5, its just looks difference. Also es6 brought arrow function these are different concept and not just syntactically prettier they are lexical functions - whereas normal functions are contextual. there are a lot of other small cool chances that es6 brought.